# Ajax call ordering HTML Elements in wrong order

Tags: jquery

I'm making an ajax call to the server code to pull more records onto the page. But it isn't coming back in order I expect it to. Below is the function that makes the Ajax call to the server code. The data from the server side code serves the data in the right order and when the call initially gets the data it's in the right order as well.

```
function GetPosts()
{
  $.ajax
  ({
      type: 'GET',
      url:  'getposts',
      data: {'pageIndex': JSON.stringify(pageIndex), 'pageSize': JSON.stringify(pageSize) },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data)
      {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              $(this).load("showpost/" + data[i], function (result) {
                  $('#container').append(result);
              })
          }
          pageIndex++;
      },

      beforeSend: function () {
          $("#progress").show();
      },
      complete: function () {
          $("#progress").hide();
      },
      error: function () {
          alert("Something went terribly wrong with infinite scrolling " + pageIndex);
      }
  })
}
```

But This is the data I see when I make the call on the page

```
<div class="posts" id="posts_25"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_24"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_23"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_22"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_21"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_20"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_19"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_18"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_17"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_16"></div>
<div id="container">
<div class="posts" id="posts_15"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_9"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_8"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_7"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_5"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_10"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_11"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_12"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_14"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_13"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_4"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_1"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_2"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_3"></div>
</div>
```

This is how the data should look when presented on the html page, the posts should be in descending order, which you can notice with the id numbers and it each time the call is made it comes in a different order.

```
<div class="posts" id="posts_25"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_24"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_23"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_22"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_21"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_20"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_19"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_18"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_17"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_16"></div>
<div id="container">
<div class="posts" id="posts_15"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_14"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_13"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_12"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_11"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_10"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_9"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_8"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_7"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_5"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_4"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_3"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_2"></div>
<div class="posts" id="posts_1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "the data I see" and "how the data should look" is the same.. I suppose you want `div.posts` to be appended in `#container`. right?

Comment: You need to look at the id numbers to see the issue

Comment: Have you checked the order on 2nd time ajax call ?

Comment: I've checked it several times over and it comes in completely different orders each time, I have a feeling it may coming in based on which is loading the fastest

Comment: You are using jQuery load() it will always fire asynchronously. So you can not guaranteed about the order. You need to load them synchronously to get desired order

Comment: Ok that's fair enough, but I'm not sure how to do that, could you possibly point me in the right direction ?

Comment: async: false, however it's deprecated and ruins user experience by taking a bit longer to load.

Answer (score 0):

When `$(this).load("showpost/" ...` are called. You have sent multiple ajax call to load `posts`. Depending on the load speed, it will return at random.

A work around for this is to prepare dom stubs/placeholder before ajax calls are sent. When it returns, you will update those stubs with each results respectively.

```
      var stubs = {};
      for (var i in data) {
          stubs[i] = $('<div></div>');
          $('#container').append(stubs[i]);
          $(this).load("showpost/" + data[i], function(result) {
              stubs[i].after(result); //insert result after stub
              stubs[i].remove(); // remove the stub
          });
      }
```

Comment: Gave that a try and unfortunately it doesn't post of the elements back